# NOT NULL constraint failed: api_article.author_id, Django_RestFramework Nested Serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework

*serializers.py*

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'username')
        model = User

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'title', 'content', 'is_public')
```

*models.py*

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_public = models. BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I tried to save jsons like this:

```json
{
        "id": 1,
        "author": {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "sakib"
        },
        "title": "blah",
        "content": "blah blah blah",
        "is_public": true
}
```

It works fine if i save an object from the admin page, But if I want to post a new object I get integrity error: Not-Null constraint failed: api_article.author_id

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the JSON data. Just pass the `id` of the author.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "author": 2,
    "title": "blah",
    "content": "blah blah blah",
    "is_public": true
}
```